# Paging3 - How to do Reverse Pagination in Chat App

Tags: android-paging-3

I am recently migrate to Paging3. However, I noticed that most of the tutorials and guides are mainly on normal pagination *(from top to bottom)*.

I need to implement the **REVERSE** pagination as user scroll to top boundary, will load for page 2,3,4..
Is there any tutorial/guide for this?

PS: Now the initial loading is working fine, but when I scroll to top-most, I have no idea how to load **Page 2** data.

**My current approach**

PagingSource

```
class ChatPagingSource(
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val roomId: String
): PagingSource<Int, Message>() {

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Message>): Int? = null

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Message> {
        return try{
            val page = params.key?: 1
            val pageSize = params.loadSize

            val call = apiService.getMessageFeedPaging(
                room_id = roomId,
                page = page,
                max = pageSize,
                exclude = EXCLUDE_TYPE
            )
            val repoItems = call.messages
            val prevKey = if(page > 1) page - 1 else null
            val nextKey = if(repoItems.isNotEmpty()) page + 1 else null

            if(repoItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                val messageList = mutableListOf<Message>()
                for (i in repoItems) {
                    val replyData = Converters.convertReplyDataAPItoReplyData(i.reply_data)

                    val msg = Converters.convertMessageAPItoMessage(replyData, i, hasError = false)
                    messageList.add(msg)
                }
                LoadResult.Page(messageList, prevKey, nextKey)
            } else {
                LoadResult.Page(listOf(), prevKey, nextKey)
            }
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

Repository

```
 fun loadRemoteMessageStream(roomId: String): LiveData<PagingData<Message>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(20),
            pagingSourceFactory = { ChatPagingSource(apiService, roomId) }
        ).liveData
    }
```

ViewModel

```
 private val _remoteMessage = chatRepository.loadRemoteMessageStream(currentRoomId)
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
        .let { it as MutableLiveData<PagingData<Message>> }

val remoteMessage: LiveData<PagingData<Message>> = _remoteMessage
```

Fragment

```
 chatViewModel.remoteMessage.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            chatAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, it)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, I will post out my own answer.
The key is to reverse `prevKey` and `nextKey` and fixed the pageSize that your API required (in my case is 20).

```
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Message> {
    val pageSize = 20
    val prevKey = if(repoItems.isNotEmpty()) page + 1 else null
    val nextKey = if(page > 1) page - 1 else null
}
```

Then, in the recyclerview, you should use `stackFromEnd = true` so that initially the recyclerview will auto-scroll to bottom.